# WooCommerce: Tax calculation on checkout page based on zip code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I get taxes calculated in the checkout page once the zip code is entered? I need to charge taxes on purchases placed from specific zip codes.

I am allowing customers to checkout without creating an account, so I can’t calculate taxes in the cart.

So, once the customer enters the zip code in the checkout page, what I need is a new field opened and then get WooCommerce AJAX triggered to calculate the taxes based on the totals from the cart (without shipping) and the "Standard" Tax Rates table.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried :) Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Added WooCommerce tag